# ubuntu(Virtualbox上)のリンク速度をethtoolを使って変えたい。

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Virtualbox上に入れたUbuntu14.04のリンク速度をethtoolを用いて変更することは可能ですか?
もし可能でしたら方法を教えてください。
コマンドラインから「ethtool -s eth0 speed 100」と打ち込むと
「cannot advertise speed」
といったエラーが出ます。また、auto-negをoffに設定できません。
どなたかご教授お願い致します。
✳補足　Virtualbox上に2台のUbuntuを立て、それらを内部ネットワークで接続しています。この2台間のリンク速度を変更して通信を行いたいです。(UbuntuAのeth0とUbuntuBのeth0が内部ネットワークでお互いに接続されています。)

以下は`sudo ethtool -s eth0 advertise 0x008`を実行した結果です。ここからspeedを100Mbpsに変更するにはどうしたらよろしいのでしょうか。

Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: umbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes

Comment: metropolisさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。Advertised link modes:が100baseT/Fullに変更されたのですが、Speedは1000Mb/sのままです。speedを変更するにはどのようにしたらよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: metropolisさん、ご返信ありがとうございます。変化はなく、`Cannot advertise speed 100`というエラーのままです、、

Comment: metropolisさん、ご返事ありがとうございます。こちらは素の状態のubuntu14.04を使用しています

Comment: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10161815395 マルチポスト

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.アダプタタイプを変えてみてもethtoolのエラーは同じでしょうか。

http://vboxmania.net/content/%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A

2.内部ネットワークではなく、hostonlyやNATにした場合に、ethtoolの実行結果に変化はありますか？

3.ゲスト側ではなくホスト側のNICに対してethtoolの実行結果はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 返信おそくなり申し訳有りません。labunixさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。1〜3試してみたところ、ethtoolのエラーは同じで実行結果に変化はありませんでした。ホストOSは無線でAPにつないでいるのですが、有線でつないでいないといけないのでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

対向も同じ設定でしょうか。

http://barikidazu.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-71.html

> sudo ethtool -s eth1 autoneg off
>   sudo ethtool -s eth1 duplex full
>   sudo ethtool -s eth1 speed 100

Comment: labunixさん、ご回答いただきありがとうございます。対抗も同じ設定(投稿文に記載してある状態)になっております。`sudo ethtool -s eth1 autoneg off`を実行してもoffにはならず、sudo ethtool -s eth1 autoneg off
sudo ethtool -s eth1 duplex fullを打ち込むと`Cannot advertise duplex full`　というエラーが返ってきます。